# Linux Question Closed as Dupe of Windows Question

Tags: discussion

I found [this Linux question](https://serverfault.com/questions/448541/how-to-know-who-ping-my-computer) about finding out who's pinging your Linux box. It's Linux-specific.

It's closed as a dupe of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/107163/how-can-i-know-when-my-computer-is-pinged) which is about finding out who's pinging your Windows box. It's Windows specific.

Why is a Linux-specific question closed as a duplicate of a Windows-specific question?

Comment: Downvoters, any justification or comments?

Comment: Wesley's answer pretty much says it: the problem is OS agnostic and the analysis methodology is identical. If you're looking for a guide on exact programs to install and how to perform the analysis, the minimum effort we'd expect is that you've tried to Google it. We're here to help you with specific problems. We don't do HOWTOs or job training.

Comment: ashes, you've already publicly exposed your misunderstanding of what duplicate questions are (though Ward very capably summarises the issue below).  Before you go exposing another misunderstanding, check out [the guide to voting on meta](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-meta).  Since votes don't affect anything on meta - your reputation is hourly re-synced to your SF rep - up/downvotes here are much more trivial "*thumbs up*" / "*thumbs down*" expressions.  Don't read anything more into them than that!

Answer (score 7):

[As Voretaq7 said](https://serverfault.com/questions/448541/how-to-know-who-ping-my-computer#comment488424_448541):

> Same principles apply: Sniff the traffic on the network, or have your local firewall log ICMP Echo requests your system sees...

The StackExchange definition of a duplicate question is that question is a dupe if the answers to one question could also apply to the other.  That's clearly the case here.

Comment: My meta post is not about pinging. It's about a Linux-specific question being closed as a duplicate of a Windows-specific question.

Comment: @ashes999 the basic answer is the same, break out a network analyser, any half decent sysadmin should be good to go from that.

Comment: @ashes999 It's not a Linux specific question being closed as a duplicate of a Windows specific question. There's nothing Linux or Windows specific about either.

Comment: @ward <3 <3 <3 <3